# error when use session with expressjs and redis

Tags: session, node.js, redis, express

I try to use session in express with redis.

 But i don't know why it get this error

```
Cannot set property 'user' of undefined
```

[here is link code](https://gist.github.com/1580250)

Comment: try without redis https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/session/app.js

Answer (score 2):

`app.use(app.router);` should go after the cookieParser and session middleware. Otherwise you won't be able to access the session inside of your routes.

Putting a stack trace next time in your question would help others help you faster.

And generally, understanding what each middleware does help prevent these kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
var express = require('express');
var redis   = require("redis");
var session = require('express-session');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var client  = redis.createClient();
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'ssshhhhh',
    // create new redis store.
    store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/',function(req,res){  
    // create new session object.
    if(req.session.key) {
        // if email key is sent redirect.
        res.redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        // else go to home page.
        res.render('index.html');
    }
});

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    // when user login set the key to redis.
    req.session.key=req.body.email;
    res.end('done');
});

app.get('/logout',function(req,res){
    req.session.destroy(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("App Started on PORT 3000");
});
```

link : https://codeforgeek.com/2015/07/using-redis-to-handle-session-in-node-js/